# Tomcat7 multi virtual host

Tags: tomcat7

I have two webapps and want to access them in different port with '/', something like 'http://localhost:8080' and 'http://localhost:8081', how to configure it?

Is it able to start server like resin 'resin.sh start -server web1'?

Comment: Might be batter asked over on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: @hoss No. I don't think it would be well received there.

Comment: My mistake,  seemed like configuration over programming